# WSAEventselect Error: 10038

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and I need help because I'm out of ideas. My WSAEventselect function returns error number 10038.

Code:

```
        // Error checking....
        if(netEvent.iErrorCode[FD_ACCEPT_BIT] != 0)
        {
            int temp1 = WSAGetLastError();
            emit ClientErrorSignal();
            return;
        }

        // Initializing socket
        if((newClient = accept(this->info->socket, NULL, NULL)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            int temp2 = WSAGetLastError();
            emit ClientErrorSignal();
            return;
        }

        // This is where the error occurs
        if(WSAEventSelect(newClient, &this->info->event, FD_READ|FD_CLOSE) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            int temp3 = WSAGetLastError();
            emit ClientErrorSignal();
            return;
        }
```

`this->info` is a struct that is passed into the thread.

```
typedef struct {
    SOCKET socket;
    int size;
    bool isTcp;
    WSAEVENT event;
} SINFO, *PSINFO;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Winsock error reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this is a `WSAENOTSOCK` error, meaning you're trying to do something with an invalid socket handle.  Without more information about where the error is occurring in your code I don't think I can offer much more advice than that, but I'd suggest checking to ensure that you're creating the socket correctly (perhaps the call to `accept` on an uninitialized socket is the culprit?)

Comment: The accept itself should initialize `newClient` socket. That's what I am confused about since accept is not throwing any errors.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be related to your problem, but the second parameter you're passing to `WSAEventSelect` is a `WSAEVENT*`, whereas the function expects a `WSAEVENT`.  Just pass the handle directly, not its address:

```
WSAEventSelect(..., info->event, ...);
```

Comment: You're very correct. How could I have been so blind...I need sleep...Thanks.